# Get multiple comparisons with GGplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I produced a plot with the standard R base function PLOT. `plot(dataframe)` This plot looks like this:
[image]

Now i want to make the same plot with GGplot2. But everything i tried failed so far.
My dataframe looks like this:

```
structure(list(tRap_pear = c(0.0350096175177328, 0.234255507711743, 
0.23714999195134, 0.185536020521134, 0.191585098617356, 0.201402054387186, 
0.220911538536031, 0.216072802572045, 0.132247101763063, 0.172753098431029
), Beeml_pear = c(0.179209909971615, 0.79129167285928, 0.856908302056589, 
0.729078080521886, 0.709346164378725, 0.669599784720647, 0.585348196746785, 
0.639355942917055, 0.544909349368496, 0.794652394149651), Mash_spear = c(0.158648548431316, 
0.53887352819363, 0.457888265527408, 0.563127988391531, 0.535626487998822, 
0.339363025936821, 0.347487640634066, 0.446668310403948, 0.327120869232769, 
0.597005214316607), tRap_spear = c(0.0401250136715237, 0.511012317625831, 
0.328979081566789, 0.518148084654934, 0.469847452665152, 0.264057161482016, 
0.312517231623128, 0.430052514388429, 0.338233671643239, 0.417881662695103
), Beeml_spear = c(0.0961259035034072, 0.70273493789764, 0.466746274696884, 
0.817805518009015, 0.722756585905275, 0.407861493627591, 0.423745193368859, 
0.534971415799068, 0.519199516553983, 0.748709415442623), Mash_pear2080 = c(0.823944540480775, 
0.816630852343513, 0.81134728399675, 0.801065036203532, 0.799630945085954, 
0.799195606444727, 0.798637867344115, 0.798478922129054, 0.798090734787886, 
0.797673368802285), Mash_spear2080 = c(0.687131069446869, 0.704882483221722, 
0.696045373880582, 0.716722524407137, 0.74354480616146, 0.684047794911021, 
0.718132260792985, 0.639437653298423, 0.671605390101442, 0.670239912705399
)), .Names = c("tRap_pear", "Beeml_pear", "Mash_spear", "tRap_spear", 
"Beeml_spear", "Mash_pear2080", "Mash_spear2080"), row.names = c("Aft1", 
"Alx3_3418.2", "Alx4_1744.1", "Arid3a_3875.1_v1_primary", "Arid3a_3875.1_v2_primary", 
"Arid3a_3875.2_v1_primary", "Arid3a_3875.2_v2_primary", "Arid5a_3770.2_v1_primary", 
"Arid5a_3770.2_v2_primary", "Aro80"), class = "data.frame")
```

I know its something with the facets of GGPlot but how to correctly implement this still remains a question to me.

Comment: Try looking at `ggpairs` in the **GGally** package.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get similar plot to `plotmatrix()` in ggplot2 package but with names on the diagonal, first, you need to reshape from wide format to long format.

This code (made by @Arun) makes all combinations of variable names (with `expand.grid()`) and then you put all data for each combination in one long data frame.

```
combs <- expand.grid(names(dataframe), names(dataframe))

out <- do.call(rbind, apply(combs, 1, function(x) {
  tt <- dataframe[, x]; names(tt) <- c("V1", "V2")
  tt <- cbind(tt, id1 = x[1], id2 = x[2])
}))
```

Next, make new data frame for texts - position of labels are calculated as mean value for each variable. Position is calculated to put label in middle of data range.

```
library(plyr)
df.text=ddply(out[out$id1==out$id2,],.(id1,id2),summarise,
                       pos=max(V1)-(max(V1)-min(V1))/2)
```

Now, replace those values were both variables are the same with NA (data on diagonals). This should be done after text data frame is made.

```
out[out$id1==out$id2,c("V1","V2")]<-NA
```

Now plot your data and use both variable ids for facetting and with `geom_text()` add texts to diagonals.

```
ggplot(data = out, aes(x = V2, y = V1)) + geom_point() +
  facet_grid(id1 ~ id2,scales="free")+
  geom_text(data=df.text,aes(pos,pos,label=id1))
```

[image]

Comment: The code works perfect for me. But i have 1 question left and dont know if i should write a new question, or just ask it in this 1. But my question is how to substitute the dots from the scatters into the rownames of the dataframe out.

Answer (score 3):

If your data is called mydf,

```
plotmatrix(mydf)
```

A warning says: "This function is deprecated. For a replacement, see the ggpairs function in the GGally package."

therefore:

```
library(GGally)

ggpairs(mydf, upper=list(continuous = "points", combo = "box"))
```

Have a look in the help page to play around with the parameters.

Answer (score 2):

I think your question is answered in this [blog post](http://schamberlain.github.io/2011/03/for-all-your-pairwise-comparison-needs/). In particular,

```
plotmatrix(iris[1:4])
```

However, this function is now depreciated, so use the `ggpairs` function in `GGally`

Comment: I cannot install that package for r 2.15.

Comment: Can you upgrade R to 3.00?

Comment: I probably can but am afraid all my other scripts will not work like they used to.

Comment: fyi - there you can read more about the function suggested by @csgillespie https://rdrr.io/cran/GGally/man/ggpairs.html