# Change dots of a ggplot to text labels

Tags: r, ggplot2

Recently i asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16280219/get-multiple-comparisons-with-ggplot2) about getting multiple graphs within 1 picture. I got some pretty good answers but 1 question still remains.

How to change dots from my scatter plot into labels?
The plot looks like this [image]

Now i want all the black dots to be changed to the rownames of the data.
The code i use for the plotting is as follows:

```
plotAll<-function(data){
  combs <- expand.grid(names(data), names(data))
  out <- do.call(rbind, apply(combs, 1, function(x) {
    tt <- data[, x]; names(tt) <- c("V1", "V2")
    tt <- cbind(tt, id1 = x[1], id2 = x[2])
  }))

  library(plyr)
  df.text=ddply(out[out$id1==out$id2,],.(id1,id2),summarise,
                pos=max(V1)-(max(V1)-min(V1))/2)
  out[out$id1==out$id2,c("V1","V2")]<-NA
  ggplot(data = out, aes(x = V2, y = V1)) + geom_point(alpha = 0.5) +
    facet_grid(id1 ~ id2,scales="fixed")+
    geom_text(data=df.text,aes(pos,pos,label=id1)) + geom_abline( slope=1 ) + 
    ggtitle("Corralation between measured & calculated affinities") +
    ylab("") + xlab("") + theme(panel.grid.minor.x=element_blank(), panel.grid.major.x=element_blank())
}
```

I know i have to change the settings of `geom_point(alpha=0.5)` to something with `geom_text(label=rownames(data))` But that deletes my axes and places the rownames onto the y-axes and into my datapoints. So probably i did something wrong with the lay out of the plot but what it is remains a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turned out to be much more difficult than I thought... the basic problem is the `NA` values - `geom_text` can't handle them. That's pretty easy to fix by doing:

```
geom_text(data = out[!is.na(out$V1),], label = "test")
```

But when you go to do `rownames` as the label it gets problematic. I didn't figure out why, but got around it quickly by adding a label column to your dataframe. Full function below.

```
plotAll<-function(data){
  combs <- expand.grid(names(data), names(data))
  out <- do.call(rbind, apply(combs, 1, function(x) {
    tt <- data[, x]; names(tt) <- c("V1", "V2")
    tt <- cbind(tt, id1 = x[1], id2 = x[2])
  }))

  library(plyr)
  df.text=ddply(out[out$id1==out$id2,],.(id1,id2),summarise,
                pos=max(V1)-(max(V1)-min(V1))/2)
  out[out$id1==out$id2,c("V1","V2")]<-NA
  out$labels <- rownames(out)
  ggplot(data = out, aes(x = V2, y = V1)) + geom_text(data = out[!is.na(out$V1),], aes(label = labels)) +
    facet_grid(id1 ~ id2,scales="fixed")+
    geom_text(data=df.text,aes(pos,pos,label=id1)) + geom_abline( slope=1 ) + 
    ggtitle("Corralation between measured & calculated affinities") +
    ylab("") + xlab("") + theme(panel.grid.minor.x=element_blank(), panel.grid.major.x=element_blank())
}
plotAll(data)
```

Comment: Yeah that was what i expected. But doing this gives me:
Error: Aesthetics must either be length one, or the same length as the dataProblems:rownames(data)

Comment: Yes... I'm having a look at it now after getting the data from your other question - I'll get back to you!

Comment: It's something in the `facet_grid()`, I think. If you change the formula to `~ v2` it's happy.

Comment: @SanderVanderZeeuw let me know if the new answer works for you

Comment: sorry for late reply was having a break. I will check it immediately

Comment: No problem - I only put it up 2 minutes ago!

Comment: It works smooth and nice. Thank you very much! i was already struggling for a few hours.